# Errors when using bibliography style plain instead of apacite?

Tags: bibliographies

I'm supposed to be using the plain bibliography style (in order to have `[1]` style references).

However, when I switch from the `apacite` to the `plain` style, I get errors.

```
%\bibliographystyle{apacite} % this works
\bibliographystyle{plain} % This gives me errors
```

The errors I get are the following (line 247 is an empty line, the previous line has two `\cite{}`:

[image: Errors with plain bibliography style]

Comment: Have you tried to delete all auxiliary files and then compile again?

Comment: The `apacite` bibliography style is supposed to be used in conjunction with the `apacite` package. If you want to switch to using `plain` you need to remove the `\usepackage{apacite}` line (and delete aux files before recompiling).

Comment: @AlanMunn That solved it! I had to remove the usepackage, thanks! If you post an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `apacite` bibliography style is supposed to be used in conjunction with the `apacite` package. If you want to switch to using `plain` you need to remove the `\usepackage{apacite}` line (and delete aux files before recompiling).